# Laravel 10 Form validate rules redirect to home

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working on a Laravel API project and created this controller function to register the API route. If I remove the validator, it works fine meaning it doesn't take me to the Laravel homepage when I send a POST request

But I can't leave it without validation so when I am trying to send a blank request to check if the validator is working or not it takes me to the homepage ( screenshot added of Postman check below and cURL )

```php
public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
            'password'  => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validatedData->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $validatedData->messages()], 422);
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->role = 0;
        $user->save();
        
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Patient registered successfully'], 201);

    }
```

and my API route is:

```php
Route::post('patient/register', [PatientController::class, 'register']);
```

[image: postman output]

[image: curl output]

Comment: It does automatic redirection for you. Hence the behaviour.

Comment: Please do not post images of text--rather, post the text itself. Thanks

Comment: @Mooshua this is just output so I can simply share it, because It doesn't need anything to copy I have that common sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:6',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['message' => $validator->errors()], 422);
}
```

Comment: I followed the Laravel latest docs don't know why it wasn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try either two ways if you want to validate with $request->validate().
The default behavior of $request->validate() is to return to previous web route with error bags.

Try it in try-catch block and manually returning errors, it will get automatically converted to JSON response.

```
try{

   $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

 catch(\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $ex){
     return $ex->validator->errors();
}
```

Or try including this header in your request.

```
Accept: application/json
```

Otherwise, **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator**, faced just do fine.

Reference

> [Laravel validation error not returning as json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187569/laravel-validation-error-not-returning-as-json-response)

Comment: It doesn't work that way I tried but the above solution works fine for me.